# Grub 2.04 does not recognize my keyboard

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu, uefi

I recently installed Xubuntu alongside my Windows 10. Now I theoretically get to choose the OS to boot in the grub screen, but I cannot use my keyboard. Here's what I already know/tried:

I don't think it has to do with my BIOS/UEFI firmware because both in UEFI menu and in the grub menu of the live-USB I installed Xubntu with, my keyboard works. Also later in the OS it is no problem.

I already tried what someone in an old Gentoo-forum-post suggested: appending `GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="usb_keyboard"` and `GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="usb usb_keyboard ohci uhci ehci"` to my `/etc/default/grub` and running `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Then for some reason I get the grub-screen with no timer, so I can't boot anything and have to change it back from my live-USB.

I also enabled all kinds of legacy support in the UEFI menu.

Lastly I can say that at the end of the Xubuntu-installation I got an error regarding grub but I only sent an error report and unfortunately didn't remember it. I thought I would just rerun the config and it would work.

Comment: If Windows is UEFI, you have to have UEFI on, and legacy/BIOS/CSM off. Often also in UEFI you need a USB setting for full support or Keyboard & mouse support. Windows & Ubuntu usually use their own drivers and work, but grub is before system boots and needs UEFI support for keyboard.

Comment: @oldfred how would I know whether legacy/BIOS/CSM is off? My asus-motherboard runs something it calls "UEFI BIOS" which I assume is just UEFI. For USB settings, I really searched for them and only found 3 legacy USB options, all of which I turned on. How would I give UEFI-support to grub?

Comment: I had an experience that my HHKB doesn't work on boot, I plugged another 10 year-old keyboard and it worked. The firmware of keyboard sometimes is too new.